# Reading data from a file and writing it to a file after sorting

Tags: c, data-structures, file-handling, qsort

I am trying to write a program that will read the data from a CSV file and sort it by using qsort and then writing it to another CSV file, but it is not working. It just opens the out.csv file and writes nothing. My problem is that I am not sure how to read a structure from a file. I am learning how to code, and I can really use some help. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong.
My data looks like this (material1  3.5    6000000 ; material2 3.2 70000 ...)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct material{
 char *name;
 double k;
 double s;
};

 int compk(const void *p1,const void *p2)
 {
     return(((struct material*)p1)->k -((struct material*)p2)->k);
 }
     int comps(const void *p1,const void *p2)
 {
    return(((struct material*)p1)->s -((struct material*)p2)->s);
 }
int main(void)
{

FILE *mFileIn, *mFileOut;
double k,s;
char name;

struct material my_materials[100];

mFileIn=fopen("C:\\Users\\Berru\\Desktop\\in.csv","r");

    if (mFileIn == NULL) {
     printf("Error opening file \n");
     return 1;
 }

 mFileOut=fopen("C:\\Users\\Berru\\Desktop\\out.csv","w");

    if (mFileOut == NULL) {
     printf("Error opening file \n");
     return 1;
 }

 int i,counter;
 for(counter=0;counter<100;counter++)
 {
     if(fscanf(mFileIn," %s %lf %lf",my_materials[counter].name,my_materials[counter].k,my_materials[counter].s)==3)
     {
         my_materials[i].name=name;
         my_materials[i].k=k;
         my_materials[i].s=s;
     } else{
         break;
     }

 }

 fclose(mFileIn);

 qsort(my_materials,counter,sizeof(*my_materials),compk);
 fprintf(mFileOut,"Sorted by k\n");
 for(i=0;i<counter;i++)
 {
     fprintf(mFileOut," %-d \t %s \t %lf \t  %lf\n",counter,my_materials[counter].name,my_materials[counter].k,my_materials[counter].s);
 }

 qsort(my_materials,counter,sizeof(*my_materials),compk);
 fprintf(mFileOut,"Sorted by s\n");

 for(i=0;i<counter;i++)
 {
     fprintf(mFileOut," %-d \t %s \t %lf \t  %lf\n",counter,my_materials[counter].name,my_materials[counter].k,my_materials[counter].s);
 }

 fclose(mFileOut);
 printf("Data is sorted\n");

 return 0;
```

Comment: *I am not sure how to read a structure from a file*. What is wrong with what you have now? What specific error or incorrect behavior are you observing? One big issue is that you are neither initialising nor incrementing `i`. But in fact you don't need that at all. Why do you think you need to `fscanf` and then overwrite the result? The `fscanf` already writes into the struct.

Comment: Can you explain it to me a little more? What would you tell me that I should do? @kaylum

Comment: Do you know what `fscanf` actually does? Next , `my_materials[i].name=name;` ask yourself what that does? What is the value of `name` at that point considering it is never set? What is the value of `i` considering it is never set. These are all basic things that you should be asking yourself.

Comment: You check the return value of fscanf to see that it worked but if it doesn't work you continue the program anyway by creating a partial (or empty) output file.